# Large Free space changes on mac when not writing to HDD

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, adobe-photoshop, hard-drive

Im creating files on PhotoShop CS5. They are 10mb a piece. HDD goes from 35 gb free to suddenly 400 mb free throughout the whole day then it suddenly alerts me of this startup disc being full. In total I only write like 200 mg a day. How it is that my computer thinks I'm writing 30GB?

Btw, I have a MAcBook Pro 17'' from June 2008 so it isnt that old.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, the undo files and/or memory requirements that enable you to undo multiple levels need a lot of space. You say that you're only writing about 200MB/day; but the way I read that, you're only writing when the files are finished.

If you were to create files one at a time, write it out, THEN move on to the next file, it could clear the space it's using.